# OpenGL Alpha Blending not working Despite using glEnable(GL_BLEND) and glBlendFunc()

Tags: c++, opengl

I am Having an issue where the blending to get transparency in OpenGL isn't working. The alpha channel is effectively just turning the color to black(might be the same color as my clear color). I have enabled blending and the blendfunc. I also have tested that I am submitting my color data correctly as the transparency isn't showing up even if I hard code it in. The geometry is just overriding all color behind it. Any tips on how to debug?

```
// Blending function for Alpha channels
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

// Allows for depth testing between z-values
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

```
#type vertex
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 a_Position;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 a_Color;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 a_TexCoord;
layout(location = 3) in float a_TexIndex;

uniform mat4 u_VPMatrix;

out vec4 v_Color;
out vec2 v_TexCoord;
out float v_TexIndex;
    
void main() {
    v_Color = a_Color;
    v_TexCoord = a_TexCoord;
    v_TexIndex = a_TexIndex;
    gl_Position = u_VPMatrix * vec4(a_Position, 1.0);
}


#type fragment
#version 330 core           

in vec4 v_Color;
in vec2 v_TexCoord;
in float v_TexIndex;


uniform sampler2D u_Textures[32];
//uniform float u_TilingFactor;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture(u_Textures[int(v_TexIndex)], v_TexCoord) * v_Color;
    
}
```

Comment: Blending only works correctly if depth tests is disabled (if it is enabled, fragments might be discarded before they can be blended) or the geometry is drawn back-to-front (if the geometry is drawn back-to-front, you don't need the depth test at all).

Comment: Okay disabling the Depth Test works, but I'd like to specify a z-value to pull geometry to the front. Is there a way to do this while preserving blending?

Comment: No. You have to draw the geometry  back-to-front.